# How to set static IP in Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 but get DNS servers IPs automatically?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, netplan

I have Ubuntu Server installation with DHCP turned on and I get DNS servers IPs automatically from my ISP.

If I want to set my IP as static I need to edit `/etc/netplan/*.yaml`, but without DHCP I apparently need to specify DNS Servers IPs for my interface. What should I do to obtain these IPs automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your IP address served by DHCP, but as a reserved number. So you configure DHCP with your mac address and tell it to supply a particular IP address against it. How this is done will depend on your DHCP software used.

If you make it static, there is no DHCP call.

To be honest, I really don't think you have described your problem properly though.